# Trying to copy year from a row and add it to column with month and days

Tags: python, pandas, date, parsing

[image: This is what I want to achieve as an end result][image: This is my Data]

Python - Pandas

I need to copy year values from a row, and add this value to a column containing day and month values. Also need to do this for 9 years data.

Plus, also, there are informations in rows with years, I want to add them at the end of the dataframe.

```
    new2= pd.DataFrame()
    for i in transposed_df[:2:10]:
        new2 = new2.append(transposed_df[i], ignore_index=True)
```

input dataframe:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame([[0,2010,2011], ["01-January",965383,1100827], ["02-February",907046,1048171], ["03-March",960178.0,1106555.0]])

    0   1   2
    0   0   2010.0  2011.0
    1   01-January  965383.0    1100827.0
    2   02-February 907046.0    1048171.0
    3   03-March    960178.0    1106555.0
```

Comment: post both input and output dataframes as text please, images cannot be copied

Comment: how can add this more readable?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)